# Why can't TupleElementNamesAttribute be applied to tuple fields?

Tags: c#, attributes, tuples, named

In C# named tuples cannot be used in another assembly because the element names only exist in source code. If you want to do so, you have to apply TupleElementNamesAttribute to the return types of methods or properties in order to let them conserve their names in the compiled assembly. However we can't use this attribute for fields. My question is why doesn't C# allow this attribute to apply to fields, so fields can also conserve their element names when used in other assemblies?

Comment: If the names are in a public API they should be visible in another assembly, I guess. But you can always re-define the names in variables `(int X, int Y) tuple = (A: 10, B: 20);`. These names do not need to match the original ones.

Comment: *why C# doesn't allow this attribute to apply to fields* - questions of the ilk "what was microsoft thinking when they made the design decision to..." are off topic

Comment: I don't ask what Microsoft was thinking when designing tuples. I don't ask particularly about this attribute. I ask about the logic. Why the logic behind allowing functions that returns named tuples to conserve their name is not applied to named tuple fields? I don't care particularly about this attribute. If they wanted to apply the same logic they could have defined a new attribute or some other mechanism. But apparently they didn't feel the need to provide such mechanism. I ask if there is any particular reason for not providing the same logic for fields.